# How to return a variable in jsx and react into a react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, jsx, sanity

I am at the very beginning of creating an icon picker for sanity.io with react icons npm package. I am stuck on trying to map over an object and returning the right code for react to work using `Object.values(ReactIcons).map...` if I just console log one of the objects values like so `ReactIcons.Fa500Px` I get the following function

```
ƒ (props) {
  return Object(__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__lib__["a" /* GenIcon */])({"tag":"svg","attr":{"viewBox":"0 0 448 512"},"child":[{"tag":"path","attr":{"d":"M103.3 344.3c-6.5-14.2-6.9-18.3 7.4-…
```

Now If I take the same code form the console.log and put it in a jsx or React component brackets like so `<ReactIcons.Fa500Px />` it renders the icon just fine

However if I try to do that inside the map method with something like this I just get a bunch of elements in the dom the look like `<x></x>`. However the console.log(x) returns a series of the functions that are the same format as the one above that I just placed inside brackets before, which resulted in a icon being rendered.

```
{Object.values(ReactIcons).map(x =>{
    return (
      <>
    {console.log(x)}
    <x/>
    </>
    );
  })}
```

My final attempt to get this to work was to create a Icon function and pass props into it and render it as a component. Which did not work but here is that attempt.

```
function Icon(props){
  return(
    <>
      {props.value}
    </>
  )
}

{Object.values(ReactIcons).map(x =>{
 return (
    <>
      {console.log(x)} 
      <Icon value={x}/> 
    </>
   );
 })}
```

Here's the entire code base in order just to make sure maybe I am putting my Icon function in the wrong place.

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import FormField from 'part:@sanity/components/formfields/default'
import PatchEvent, {set, unset} from 'part:@sanity/form-builder/patch-event'
import * as ReactIcons from 'react-icons/fa'

console.log(ReactIcons);

const createPatchFrom = value => PatchEvent.from(value === '' ? unset() : set(String(value)))

function Icon(props){
  return(
    <>
      {props.value}
    </>
  )
}


class IconPickerCustom extends React.Component{

    static propTypes = {
        value: PropTypes.string,
        onChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired
    };

    render = () =>{
        const {type, value, onChange} = this.props
        return (
          <>
            <FormField label={type.title} description={type.description}>
              <input
                type="text"
                value={value === undefined ? '' : value}
                onChange={event => onChange(createPatchFrom(event.target.value))}
                ref={element => this._inputElement = element}
              />
            </FormField>
            {Object.values(ReactIcons).map(x =>{
              return (
                <>
              {console.log(x)} // has same result as console log below, except it is all the icons
              <Icon value={x}/> //neithr works
              <x /> //neither works
              </>
              );
            })}
            {console.log(ReactIcons.Fa500Px)}
            <ReactIcons.Fa500Px/>
          </>
        )
    }
}

export default IconPickerCustom;
```

Comment: Do you have a minimal runnable example that I can clone? I've tried in a Codesandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-davinci-5yr5k) but I can't add the Sanity plugin code as `import "part:..."` is not working outside of Sanity Studio.

Comment: You want the icons in a select dropdown? Or just aligned in the DOM as buttons?

Comment: Here's a repo with a working sanity studio with the code in it in the file https://github.com/wispyco/sanity-studio-icon in the file here https://github.com/wispyco/sanity-studio-icon/blob/master/schemas/components/IconPickerCustom.js

Comment: @AWolf for now just aligned as buttons, I'm still figuring out how the UI is gonna work because there are a lot of icons, I'll probably have to implement a search but for now I just want to even output the icons at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got help form the sanity slack, and this ended up solving my problem

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import FormField from 'part:@sanity/components/formfields/default'
import PatchEvent, {set, unset} from 'part:@sanity/form-builder/patch-event'
import * as ReactIcons from 'react-icons/fa'

// const createPatchFrom = value => PatchEvent.from(value === '' ? unset() : set(String(value)))

const Icon =({name}) =>{
  const TagName = ReactIcons[name];
  return !!TagName ? <TagName /> : <p>{name}</p>;
}

const Box = ({icon}) =>{
  return(
    <>
        {icon.map((iconsz) => {
            return(
              <>
              <button>
                <Icon name={iconsz}/>
              </button>

              </>
            )
          }     
        )}
    </>
  ) 
}

class IconPickerCustom extends React.Component{

    constructor(props){
      super(props)
      const arr = [];

      Object.keys(ReactIcons).map(go => { 
        arr.push(go);
          this.state = {icon: arr};
        }
      )
      this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)

    }

    // createPatchFrom = value => PatchEvent.from(value === '' ? unset() : set(String(value)));

    handleChange = event => {
      const value = event;
      const arr = [];
      Object.keys(ReactIcons).map(go => 
        { 
          if(go.toLowerCase().includes(value)){
            arr.push(go);
          } 
          this.setState({
            icon: arr
          });
        }
      )
    };

    render = () =>{
      const {icon} = this.state

        return (
          <>
            <input
              type="text"
              onChange={event => this.handleChange(event.target.value)}
            />
            <Box icon={icon}/>
          </>
        )
    }
}

export default IconPickerCustom;
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you would like to loop in the object key instead

```
            {Object.keys(ReactIcons).map(x =>{
               let Elm = ReactIcons[x]
              return (
                <Elm /> 
              );
            })}
```

I'm just guessing I'm not sure

Comment: I tried the keys, but I need the values. Thanks tho.

Comment: the keys just give me the name like FaIcon so on, where as the value gives me everything that needs to go in the component

Comment: `Object.keys` like Fadi wrote will work or with `Object.values` you can write it like ```{
  Object.values(ReactIcons).map((Icon, index) =>{
    return <Icon key={index}/>;
  })
}```

Comment: @AWolf, it works with .values now it had to be a capital X to recongize it as a react component.